Function components cannot be given refs. MUI v5 Autocomplete
i'm trying to use custom component for ListboxComponent prop in Autocomplete MUI v5, but i'm getting this error:

Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Autocomplete component:
    <Autocomplete
    // other props...
    ListboxComponent={p => {
          // p is a type HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>

          const props = {
            ...p,
            test: 'test'
          }
          return <ListBox {...props} />
        }}
    <Autocomplete/>

ListBox component:
'use client'
import { Children, cloneElement, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { useAutocompleteContext } from '../../context/AutocompleteContext'
import type { HTMLAttributes, ReactElement, Ref } from 'react'
import * as S from './styled'

const ListBoxComponent = (props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, ref: Ref<HTMLElement>) => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props
  const { totalRecords, options, loading, handleNextFetch } = useAutocompleteContext()

  const hasMore = options.length < totalRecords

  return (
    <S.InfiniteScrollComponent
      next={() => handleNextFetch()}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      dataLength={options.length}
      isLoading={loading}
      loadingIcon="table"
      maxHeight={80}>
      {Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
        cloneElement(child as ReactElement, { ...rest, key: `option-${index}` })
      )}
    </S.InfiniteScrollComponent>
  )
}

export const ListBox = forwardRef<HTMLElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>(
  ListBoxComponent
)

If use this variant it will works without warning, but i want to forward my own props so as not to use Context
<Autocomplete
   // other props...
   ListboxComponent={ListBox}
<Autocomplete/>

In both approaches it works properly as needed

Looks like you do not use ref inside of your custom component:
 <S.InfiniteScrollComponent

      // here we pass ref prop
      ref={ref}

      next={() => handleNextFetch()}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      dataLength={options.length}
      isLoading={loading}
      loadingIcon="table"
      maxHeight={80}>
      {Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
        cloneElement(child as ReactElement, { ...rest, key: `option-${index}` })
      )}
    </S.InfiniteScrollComponent>

Also, make sure that you use actual wrapped ListBox but unwrapped ListBoxComponent. That one may be actual reason of your error message.

I tried to pass ref inside of InfiniteScrollComponent, but error still is
